# Single Sign On with Spring Security OAuth2 and JWT

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement Single Sign On with Spring Security OAuth2 and JWT.
I use two separate applications:

An Authorization Server – which is the central authentication mechanism

Client Application: the applications using SSO

When a user tries to access a secured page in the client app, they’ll be redirected to authenticate first, via the Authentication Server.

And I am using the Authorization Code grant type out of OAuth2 to drive the delegation of authentication.

**Authorization server:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.class);


  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


  @Bean
  public TokenStore tokenStore() {
      return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
      JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
      converter.setSigningKey("abcd");
      return converter;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
      DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
      defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
      defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
      defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
      return defaultTokenServices;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientDetailsServiceConfigurer) throws Exception {
    clientDetailsServiceConfigurer
    .inMemory()
        .withClient("webapp")
        .secret("Pass")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "refresh_token", "password", "authorization_code")
        .scopes("user_info")
        .autoApprove(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {    
    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
    .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
  }


  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
      endpoints
              .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
  }

}
```

*Security Configuration on Authorization Server*

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

  @Value("${ldap.url}")
  private String ldapUrl;

  @Value("${ldap.userDnPatterns}")
  private String ldapUserDnPatterns;

  @Autowired
  private PersonService personService;

  @Autowired
  private RoleService roleService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
      http.requestMatchers()
          .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
          .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .permitAll();
  } // @formatter:on


  @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
     .authenticationProvider(this.ldapAndDatabaseAuthenticationProvider());
  }

  @Bean(name="ldapAuthenticationProvider")
  public AuthenticationProvider ldapAndDatabaseAuthenticationProvider(){
    LdapUserDetailsMapper userDetailsMapper = new LdapUserDetailsMapper();
    userDetailsMapper.setRoleAttributes(new String[]{"groupMembership"});

    LdapAndDatabaseAuthenticationProvider provider = 
        new LdapAndDatabaseAuthenticationProvider(
            this.ldapAuthenticator(), 
            this.ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(),
            this.personService);
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsMapper);

    return provider;
  }

  @Bean( name = "ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" )
  public LdapAndDatabaseAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(){
    return new LdapAndDatabaseAuthoritiesPopulator(this.contextSource(), "", roleService);
  }

  @Bean( name = "ldapAuthenticator" )
  public LdapAuthenticator ldapAuthenticator() {

      BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator( this.contextSource() );
      authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[]{"cn={0},ou=prod,o=TEMP"});

      return authenticator;
  }

  @Bean( name = "contextSource" )
  public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {

      DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource =
              new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource( ldapUrl );
      return contextSource;
  }


}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
server.context-path=/auth
security.basic.enabled=false
```

When I login the client application, It correctly forwards to Authorization Server for Single Sign On.
I enter the user credentials. User successfully get authenticated, but then I see the below error on browser:

> OAuth Error
>
> error="invalid_grant", error_description="A redirect_uri can only be
>   used by implicit or authorization_code grant types."

URL Shows:
http://localhost:8888/auth/oauth/authorize?client_id=webapp&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/jwt/webapp&response_type=code&state=LGvAzj

I also see the below at the log:

```
02:14:43.610 [http-nio-8888-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping/getHandlerInternal Looking up handler method for path /oauth/authorize 
02:14:43.614 [http-nio-8888-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping/getHandlerInternal Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView  org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Str ing>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)] 
02:14:43.849 [http-nio-8888-exec-6] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.AuthorizationEndpoint/handleOAuth2Exception Handling OAuth2 error: error="invalid_grant", error_description="A redirect_uri can only be used by implicit or authorization_code grant types."
```

Can you please help me to find the problem?

**UPDATE**
Actually, Dur is right. This configuration is correct and works fine. I had another configuration file which configures JdbcClientDetails and it was overwriting the clientDetailsService created with inmemory in this configuration.

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint in `DefaultRedirectResolver` to check the grant types of your client? You configured `authorization_code` in your authorization server, so it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it. Do I need to do anything from the Client side about the grant type - authorization_code? I just set @EnableOAuth2Sso for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter on the client.

Comment: I was confused, because Spring Security Oauth2 uses two literals for authorization code: `code` (as query parameter) and `authorization_code`(for client configuration on server). The URL looks right and your configuration looks right, but the exception says, that your configuration is wrong. That's strange, so you have to see, if your configured client is really used.